# yocto fails to build mono-xsp

Tags: mono, yocto

everyone !

I've build a system using **Yocto Project** successfully, including meta-mono etc. But now that I need to add **mono-xsp** to that system, and the build for this package fails.
I've tried the same build on Ubuntu18 and Centos7 hosts with the same results.
It appears to me that the actual target platform (iMX6UL / Zedboard / x86) does not matter as I'm getting the same result on all of these.

[build_log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FX78R7c9G-iQV0tDbScE7YhYfO6PH6t-)

[error_log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qCnHBkqjmFnNQEq9iTbUryTXjfxU5cNB)

Could anyone provide assistance in solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is right here:

```
**Error**: You must have `libtool' installed to compile mono_fpm
```

just install it:

```
$ sudo apt install libtool
```